# stored procedure for Arabic letters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was facing a little problem in how to write a stored procedure for Arabic characters

my goal is:

I'm having temp table and main table in sql server !! from through some files data Will inserted into temp table from that table I need to validate in that table only one column data will be insert some times by English Text or Arabic Text

temp details data will be passed to main table at that position I need to write a stored procedure if that field data which contains Arabic Data means then I need to update a column in main table flag to 1

so how can I match in stored procedure that data was in

Comment: You need to make sure you're using UTF-8 **everywhere,** and specifying the encoding when that's not an option. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: hi matt, thanks for replying ! but i dint get your reply clearly can you explain clearly please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If I understood you correctly, you want to identify whether the column data is non-English unicode or is it just English characters. If that's what you're trying to do, check out a solution at:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1061981-338-1.aspx#bm1062095